# Пробросить UTM метки через редирект .htaccess

Tags: редирект

Добрый день.

Выкупаем трафик из рекламных сетей и схема слива построена следующим образом:
*Рекламная сеть -> домен-прокладка (301 редирект через .htaccess) -> TDS -> Лендинг*

Такая схема нужна для А/B тестирования лендинга.

В .htaccess редирект следующего вида:

> Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On RewriteRule (.*)
>   http://tds.ru/HxxJFH [R=301,L]

Проблема в том, что редирект режет UTM метки из рекламной сети.

Как их правильно пробросить?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: `[R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, но такой вариант не помогает

Comment: Прошу прощения - ваша подсказка работает.
Проблема в ТДСке.
Она режет метки.